# Can't use Internet effectively after password change for office web Proxy on Mac

Tags: network, google-chrome, password, proxy

We have an Internet/office web proxy for http and https, pretty common proxy.   Every so often we have to reset our password.  On a Windows machine, the password change is automatic and is propagated through out all the software that uses the Internet including any services running.

With OS X Yosemite or the common software included it seems that the password change against the proxy never takes so that account typically gets locked out by requests through software running on the Mac making an Internet request.

For example:

1. Proxy Password requires change
2. I manually enter the username and updated password within the Network Proxy system settings
3. Open Chrome
4. Account locked out...because Chrome is not using the updated password or some other process has made Internet requests and locked out the account.

I even have tried to run Wireshark and see what requests a made.  Because the requests are encrypted under SSL so it is hard to tell.

I suspect the following software is not taking the proxy change.  So technically it is not a OS X problem. But Windows software seem to work fine after these password changes.

- Apple iTunes, I believe some service is making requests to the Internet with the old password?
- Apple Store/Updates
- Lasted Chrome for OSX, seems run services in the background and that proxy setting may be different the network setting proxy?
- Possible the Mail application, has my password set.
- In my .profile file, I set the http_proxy and https_proxy.  I updated these to the correct password.
- Do I need to delete Internet username/passwords in the keychain?

This is on OSX 10.10.4 - Yosemite

Has anyone experienced this or have advice?   For now, I have to just shutdown the OSX machine, if I restart it, my account will be locked out a few minutes.
... 
The software on the machine is pretty common, I use Chrome regularly, XCode, TextWrangler, Mail.  I mention this because I wonder if that software could be make requests in the background?

Comment: Please add the web proxy software (name) and if it is integrated in Active Directory (if you use Active Directory at the office at all). Additionally: is your Mac domain member?

Comment: I don't know the proxy software.  We use Active Directory.     I don't know about the last question.  Dns configuration entries have to be pointed to our company dns.  One main issue, some software will take the latest proxy setting, some software won't.  Restarts don't fix the issue.

Comment: I meant: is your Mac member of the Active Directory (domain)